# Program launches only as root but not normally

Tags: launcher, sudo, matlab

I installed MATLAB in the home directory. Now when I try to launch it normally from the bin folder, it starts up and then gives an error that says:

```
Internal error: No write permission on directory /home/uname/.matlab/Rxxxxx/temp014c0x3...
```

But it launches when I run it using sudo. So, I'm not sure what exactly is happening. This basically prevents me from using a launcher for it, as every time this error pops up. I don't want to run it as root.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

Just give a recursive write permission to `.matlab` directory,

```
sudo chmod -R 776 /home/uname/.matlab
```

Incase of directories, `776 -> drwxrwxrw-`

Incase of files,         `776 -> -rwxrwxrw-`

Comment: works! this seems due to starting matlab with sudo, which makes your ~/.matlab owned by root. Afterwards, you can't start as your own user.

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands:

```
sudo chown -R uname:uname /home/uname/.matlab/Rxxxxx/temp014c0x3
sudo chmod -R 700 /home/uname/.matlab/Rxxxxx/temp014c0x3
```

They should restore default permissions to the files.